# Howto sync or migrate Outlook 2016 settings?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, sync, microsoft-office-2016

As far as OL is part of the very nice Office 365 home Package, which allows to install Outlook on many computers at home, which are bound to my MS-Account, there should be an official way to sync or mirgrate all the setting like emails, IMAP Settings, Calendar and Contacts between computers without an Exchange server?

Afaik Visual Studio does this with settings when you log in with your VS account...

I got this link from a MS support help desk: http://office365.4team.biz/sync-outlook-between-devices.aspx
Not sure whether this relys on an 3rd party tool, but it clearly advertises the features I try to get it work.

when I try it by enabling sync only with setup of a IMAP Account, nothing happens in form a sync of settings.

Comment: Why would you configure the account using IMAP when you're using Outlook 2016 and EOL? Just use a normal exchange configuration and everything will be synced between devices as desired.

Comment: @SamuelNicholson I do not understand?! What is EOL? I am talking about a normal private configuration, so there is no server at home nor enough money to spent for Exchange online cloud...